Can the brick opening for an exterior door be close to the same size as the door?
I'm trying to turn a window into a door. The house is 1930s with brick veneer. Because the window is next to two 90 degree corner, we cannot make the brick opening any larger. Any door will have to fit into the same opening as the current window.
I've had a few contractors come out to give me quotes, and while I haven't been impressed with any of them, they all noted that due to the existing brick opening (32.5") we would need to put in a 30" door.
Today one came out that said he would be able to fit a 32" door, but instead of brick moulding he would have a trim piece that covered the gap between the jamb and the brick.
Here is a diagram:

Is it possible to fit a 32" door in this opening? Why are brick openings supposed to be so much larger than the rough opening?

Brick is usually much harder to remove if something bigger than the door opening is to come though.  If depends more on what the door is used for.  Just for people 30 inch is okay.  Stoves/freezers/big stuff, then every 1/2 inch that can be removed easy, counts.

It really depends where the hinges need to go.  If the top hinge is located below the brick, I don't see why the last contractor's idea won't work.

I should have clarified. The brick is the exterior side, and the door will be an inswing. Is this what you mean by the hinge below the brick?

The door is going to fit in the opening inside of the brick, not between the brick.  The rough opening is the dimension that is important, not the opening in the brick veneer. (which was applied to the window dimension.)
That contractor is forward thinking and a problem solver.  His solution will work. The other contractors looked at what was easiest for them.
If you are not worried about the size of the trim along the door frame it is a perfect way to get you a bigger door. The trim is just decorative and provides some sealing, but is not structural.

If the existing rough opening is smaller than required for a 32” door, how difficult is increasing the rough opening?

@Sandytrean,  That is something I cannot answer, but generally it is not feasible without substantial more work. The cost would be unrealistic to be rewarded with a couple of inches.

so if I pull off the window trim and the rough opening is large enough for the 32” door I should be good. If not I’ll go with a 30” door. My biggest concern is finding out after we open a hole in the house that the door we ordered won’t work.

I thought in your question, you had consulted and the 3rd contractor verified that the rough opening was large enough.  Contractors know that with a 32 inch door you need a 34 inch wide rough opening.  Your drawing shows a rough opening substantially larger than the 32".

That portion of the diagram is not accurate, I wasn’t considering the rough opening a limiting factor when I made it. The contractor has only measured to the window. Would he be able to assume the thickness of the window to reason the rough opening enough?
If I peruse this I think I would first remove the interior window trim so I could confirm the rough opening.

I would trust his instincts.  Just don't order a $ 5000 door that can't be returned.
